# Error: socket hang up

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var util = require("util");
```

while am running following code am getting

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1568:2
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

code

```
var sendresult = function (result) {
    console.log(result)
    var post_data ={"result": result};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(post_data))
  var options = {
    host: '172.16.2.107',
    path: '/senddata',
    port: '9080',
    method: 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',     
        'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }     

  };
 console.log("INSIDE-------------------------------------------------------")
    var post_req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });

        req.on('error', function (err) {
    //handle error here
});
  });

  // post the data
  post_req.write(post_data.toString());
  post_req.end();

}
sendresult("dataaaaaaaaa")
```

whats wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `post_data.length` does not exist because `post_data` is not a string.

So change this:

```
var post_data ={"result": result};
```

to this:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({"result": result});
```

And you should really use `Buffer.byteLength(post_data)` instead of `post_data.length` for your `Content-Length` in case `post_data` should ever contain utf8 characters or similar. `Buffer.byteLength()` always calculates byte count whereas `string.length` returns character count, which may not always be the same as the byte count.